# Is there a way to directly import or open local files from Microsoft Azure Notebooks without uploading them to the Azure cloud?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, azure-notebooks

I am trying to find a way that I can run commands to either open applications/files from my local machine or import files from my local machine in Microsoft Azure Notebooks without uploading them directly to the Azure cloud. Does anyone know if this is possible or if who/where is a better place to ask?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The jupyter is run a micro-server, which is hosted on the Azure. You can only used the data on the Azure cloud. Been there, wished that, but no.